# How to get remaining time left before authentication cookie expires in Asp.Net core 2.0 identity

Tags: authentication, cookies, timeout, asp.net-core-2.0, identity

This is how Authentication has been added

```
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                options =>
                {
                    options.LoginPath = new PathString("/");
                    //options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
                    options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict;
                    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
                    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);

                });
```

but how do i read the ExpireTimeSpan value to find the time remaining before cookie expires. 
Please help!